# How to return the in-ordered embedded document by the field name

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection stores the player's name as the field and their opponents' names and rounds played as the embedded document.

```
"player1" : { "player2": 10,"player3": 25,"player4":8,"player5": 12}
```

It means that `"player1"` played 10 rounds with `player2`, 25 rounds with `player3`, 8 rounds with `player4`and 12 rounds with `player5`.

Ultimately I would like to query the top 3 opponents who played the most rounds with a specific player. I want to get their names and rounds played and have them in descending order by the rounds.

So for `player1` I would like to return `"player3":25, "player5":12,"player2":10`

Now the closest I have go so far is do `db.collection.distinct("player1")` and it will return me an array in which the embedded document lies in the same order:

```
[ { "player2": 10,"player3": 25,"player4":8,"player5": 12} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `3.4.4` version and use `$objectToArray` & `$arrayToObject` to switch between dynamic keys and label value pair.

This is one way to achieve what you are after without changing your structure.

Stage 1 through 3: Convert the dynamic keys into key value pair followed by `$match` on `player1`.

Stage 4 through 7: Project `player` and `opponent` and use `$objectToArray` to  convert the dynamic opponent keys into key value pair followed by `$unwind` + `$sort` + `$limit`.

Stage 8 & 9: Group back the `opponent` into array of key value pairs followed by `$arrayToObject` to convert the key value pairs into dynamic keys.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$project: {keyvalarr: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"} }},
 {$unwind:"$keyvalarr"},
 {$match:{"keyvalarr.k":"player1"}},
 {$project:{player:"$keyvalarr.k", opponent: {$objectToArray: "$keyvalarr.v"}},
 {$unwind:"$opponent"}, 
 {$sort:{"opponent.v":-1}}, 
 {$limit:3},
 {$group:{_id:null, player:{$first:"$player"}, opponent:{$push:"$opponent"}}},
 {$project:{result: {$arrayToObject:"$opponent"}}}
 ])
```

You have to change your structure to something like below for lower versions and you can make use of indexes. (Preferred)

```
{player:"player1", opponent: [{player:"player2", rounds: 10},{player:"player3", rounds: 25}, {player:"player4", rounds: 8}, {player:"player5", rounds: 12}]}
```

You can simplify to below aggregation pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$match:{"player":"player1"}},
 {$unwind:"$opponent"}, 
 {$sort:{"opponent.rounds":-1}}, 
 {$limit:3},
 {$group:{_id:null, player:{$first:"$player"}, opponent:{$push:"$opponent"}}}
 ])
```